# Check if struct string array contains elements of another string array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, contains, string-comparison

I created an array of struct elements. These structs get to contain an array of strings. I want to check if these strings happen to be in another array of strings.

How can I do that or what tools should I look into?

I found that I can use a command called "Set", but it doesn't seem to work arrays within a struct.

```
import UIKit

// Define structure
struct Drink {
    var name: String
    var content: Array<String>
    var amount: Array<Int>
    var desc: String
}

// Define drinks
var mojito = Drink(name: "Mojito", content: ["Rum","Club soda"], amount: [4,20], desc: "Summer drink")
var vodkaJuice = Drink(name: "Vodka juice", content: ["Vodka","Juice"], amount: [4,20], desc: "Cheap alcohol")
var list = [mojito,vodkaJuice]

// Define what ingredients you have
var stock = ["Gin", "Vodka", "Juice", "Club soda"]
```

How do I make a list of drinks I can make from what I have?

Comment: Splitting the names of ingredients from the amounts of ingredients like that is a recipe for lots of pain down the road. I strongly suggest you group them together into something like an `Ingredient` struct.

Comment: So you suggest i should make another struct called ingredients, then make content and amount pairs in an array inside the drink struct?
Sounds like a lot of writing, but  yeah i guess im less likely to get lost :)

Comment: Precisely! The amount of writing should never deter you from writing better code. If anything, this will save you writing in the long term, because it simplifies so many operations. For example, what happens when you decide that you want to sort the ingredients by their amounts? Sorting the amounts is easy, but then how will you rearrange the names to match? Or how would you add in prices, or any other data pertaining to ingredients?

Comment: There's a name for this btw, it's called "primitive obsession". Check this out: https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Set` instead of an array so you can simply do a subset check:

```swift
import UIKit

// Define structure
struct drink {
    var name : String
    var content : Set<String> // we use a Set instead
    var amount : Array<Int>
    var desc : String
}

// Define drinks
var mojito = drink(name: "Mojito", content: ["Rum","Club soda"], amount: [4,20], desc: "Summer drink")
var vodkaJuice = drink(name: "Vodka juice", content: ["Vodka","Juice"], amount: [4,20], desc: "Cheap alcohol")
var list = [mojito,vodkaJuice] 

// Define what ingredients you have
var stock = ["Gin", "Vodka", "Juice", "Club soda"]

// find all instances of drinks where their contents
// are subsets of what you have in stock
let drinks = list.filter { $0.content.isSubset(of: stock) }
```

The importance of using sets instead of "for-loops inside for-loops" is performance. Set uses an internal hash table to look up an item in an extremely fast fashion. So the overall complexity of your lookups would be O(N.logM) for N items in list and M items in stock.

If you had done it with for loops, its complexity would be O(N.M) which could take longer and consume more battery depending on the number of items you have.

That doesn't mean you should always use sets though. Sets have tradeoffs. They bring in performance but their initial construction is slower and they don't support duplicate items. Use them only in specific cases like this. Never use sets because "they are faster", use them when they solve your specific problem.

I strongly recommend skimming over those additional data structures provided by Swift's runtime so you'll know which one to use and when.

Comment: It would be better to group content and amount into a subgroup

Comment: @LeoDabus you can't use `isSubset` without an amount then. Set loses its practicality that way.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu You only need one set. Either the stock, or the drink ingredients. There's no need to have both be sets.

Comment: @Alexander you're right, only the content needs to be a `Set`, or the comparison should be done with isSuperset instead.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu Although I would implement this different. I would use a dictionary (the maps `String` ingredient names to `Ingredient(name:quantity:)` structs), and intersection on those.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I did think about going through all the commands of swift. I just find it hard to differentiate and remember the terms, but i bet i will learn over time!

Comment: @Alexander I also agree with your recommendation about putting ingredient and amount together in a separate structure, but it probably requires some protocols to be implemented to make it compatible with a Set, which might be too complicated for a beginner at the moment.